# 4G-AC53U bridge to pfsense router

Tags: networking

I have an 4G-AC53U and I only want the router to receive and send 4g signals but the routing to be handled by my pfsense router.

How do I get this to work?

Comment: Do you have a wired ISP connection you would also like access to in addition to the cellular connection? Or is this just setting up the 4g as a wan interface? Is this the community edition of pfsense? **Please answer these in your question and not the comments!**

Comment: I want to set up the 4g router as a WAN interface. Yes it is the community edition.

Comment: Currently dealing with holiday season stuff. If no one beats me to it, I'll be back to provide setup instructions.